# Web comedy sketch about a naive superhero who keeps enacting extreme solutions to crime

Tags: story-identification, super-hero

I watched this somewhere in the last year, I think as a YouTube Short. It was one of those pieces where [the same actor plays all of the characters in slightly different costumes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TalkingToThemself). Said actor was a young black man with a generic American accent. I don't recall his hairstyle. The basic thrust of the video was the superhero telling the other guy (his roommate?) about how he'd solved crime, and couldn't understand why people thought it was so hard. I believe his initial solution involved going to every prison in the world, and throwing them into the sun, thereby getting rid of all of the criminals. When informed that not everybody in prison is actually guilty, he disappeared, and then reappeared, and told the other guy that he had fixed his problem by bringing everyone back to life and then setting everyone free from the jails. The other guy, visibly trying to keep his cool, reminds him that some actual dangerous people are in jail, and just setting everyone free because they might possibly be innocent is also irresponsible. I forget what his next step was in the video, but as I recall it, it was similarly ill-informed.

I think that, as the roommate tried to grapple with the superheroes actions, they use the effect of focusing in on his face, while the superheroes voice was speaking in a muted manner in the background. I don't think the superhero in question was wearing any sort of elaborate costume. In fact, he might have just been dressed in regular civilian clothing.

I know that I watched several other videos with this actor. Two that I can remember details of (pretty sure it's the same guy):

1. Premise of "Mortal Kombat match starts in his house" where he's initially protesting them fighting where they could break all his stuff and getting ready to take a bat or other improvised weapon to them, beginning to recoil as they get more violent and start throwing fireballs, and then being visibly scared for his life when the fatality happens.
2. One where I think someone else plays a character, where he's a superhero (street-level, I get the impression) who's been caught sneaking in by his father (also black). He's denying that he's the superhero, claiming that it's a costume for a party, etc, with his father obviously certain he is the superhero. Then, as they're arguing, a very loud mugging happens right outside the door, with the guy still insisting he's not the superhero and visibly wanting to get away so that he can rescue the person with very pointed dialogue by the victim along the lines of "Oh my goodness, I'm being mugged. If only Superhero were here..." "Oh God. I've been shot. But if Superhero showed up, I could still be taken to a hospital." "I'm dying now from a gunshot which Superhero could have saved me from, or at least taken me to the hospital..." all while the father stares at his son.

Comment: This sounds funny, and I shall enjoy watching it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like ["When your roommate is a misguided super hero."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRfzwuaYoHI) by CalebCity.

> HERO: So I was watching a documentary, right? And it was talking about how private companies benefit, like, they financially benefit from mass incarceration of people, right? Like, like *mad* people.
>
> ROOMMATE: Oh yeah, I heard about something like that.
>
> HERO: Right, right. So I was like, dang, that's messed up, right? Like, people are benefiting from the mistakes of others, and it is like... that's... that's cool? Like, that's, that's kind of corrupt, right?
>
> ROOMMATE: Yeah, I could... I could see that, like, getting corrupt.
>
> HERO: You feel me? Right. So this is what I did. I didn't even finish the documentary. I used my super speed and flight, and I just went to all the jails in the world, and just... flew them as high as they could go until they popped like balloons. They popped like balloons! It was crazy.
>
> ROOMMATE: [dismayed expression] ...you did what?

Comment: Thank you. The channel name sounds immediately familiar now that I see it.

Comment: Which would make the other two https://www.youtube.com/shorts/qAo1dOo1KLk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UNY2uluj5k, and I was wrong about another actor being involved.